# How to prove $x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no rational roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I know I can set $x = \frac{p}{q}$ and then multiply everything and then show there is a contradiction but is there an easier way to do this? like by some theorem?

Comment: Well, the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) is simple enough to use.

Comment: Rational roots of this monic polynomial are integers, and if any integer root exist, then it should divide the free coefficient. Two chances only, but $\pm 1$ is not a root (checking once modulo two).

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2B1%3D0) seems to support the $theorem$ but the rational root theorem mentioned above may be the key to your $proof$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:**

**1.** Use [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

**2.** See possible solutions would be $1$ and $−1$.

**3.** Evaluate them to conclude there is no rational roots.